# OpenShift Rest Web Service using Jersey not working

Tags: rest, web, jersey, openshift

I am working on an application which has a Web UI, developed using Struts2.   The same application also exposes a Rest based Web Service. For which I am using Jersey and Jsr311.

My problem is that when I run the app on Openshift Tomcat 6.0 (JBoss EWS 1.0),  the UI works perfectly fine,  but the moment I try to access the Web Service, I am getting the following exception:

```
**HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet Jersey Web Application threw exception**

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors$Closure
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1680)
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1526)
com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.WebApplicationProviderImpl.createWebApplication(WebApplicationProviderImpl.java:55)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.WebApplicationFactory.createWebApplication(WebApplicationFactory.java:66)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.create(ServletContainer.java:391)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.create(ServletContainer.java:306)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:605)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:208)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:373)
com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:556)
javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:212)
org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:652)
org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744
```

The same application, when I run in eclipse on my local machine is running perfectly fine. Please help as I am not able to move forward with this.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you have all of your dependencies specified in your pom.xml file, and also make sure that you are using the same version of Java on OpenShift that is being used on your local machine with Tomcat (Java 6 vs Java 7).  Also note that OpenShift uses OpenJDK instead of the Sun JDK.